# Listing every first, second, third... elements in sublist

Tags: python, list

How do I list together the first, second, third and so on elements from each sub list?

```
> main_list = [[2,3,10],[5,8,1]]
```

The expected answer should be:

```
> new_list = [[2,5],[3,8],[10,1]]
> #The first sub list from new_list [2,5] contains the first elements from the sub lists in main_list
> #The second sub list from new_list [3,8] contains the second elements from the sub lists in main_list
> #This pattern continues for all elements in main_list
```

**I need a simple code that does not require the use of numpy or groupby.**

So far my code only lists the first element for each sub list within `main_list`.

```
> new_list = [item[0] for item in main_list]
> # this gives answer of [2,5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use list-comprehension with list unpacking, and `zip`

```py
>>> [[*items] for items in zip(*main_list)]
[[2, 5], [3, 8], [10, 1]]
```

- `zip(*main_list)` will unpack the `main_list` and create `zip` object that lets you iterate each inner lists parallely, and `[*items]` will unpack the tuple coming from iterating `zip` and will create the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest`, for example this code:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

main_list = [[2,3,10],[5,8,1]]

print(list(zip_longest(*main_list)))
```

produces the result `[(2, 5), (3, 8), (10, 1)]`

Comment: If he didn't want `numpy`, I guess `itertools` is not better...

Comment: actually i could have done it with `zip()` as well but just incase one sublist will be bigger than the others..